# php call function in Class that extends values from another calss

Tags: php, class, inheritance, extend

I am calling a function from a class that extends the value from another class.
2 question:
1. this is the right way?
2. I can't call the function getTaskID, got error: `Call to undefined method PythonTask::taskID()`

TaskC.php

```
class Task{
protected  $taskID=0;

  public function __construct(){}    
}

class PythonTask extends Task{


    private $isCustom=0;
    public function __construct($taskID=0,$isCustom=0){
       parent::__construct();
       $this->taskID=$taskID;
       $this->isCustom=$isCustom;
    }

   public function getTaskID(){
      return $this->taskID();
   }

}
```

---

```
include_once('TaskC.php');

$pythonTask = new PythonTask;
echo $pythonTask->getTaskID();
```

any advice? and recommendation for a good extends guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change

```
return $this->taskID();
```

to

```
return $this->taskID;
```

`taskID()` is not a function